# Show $\sim:=\{(X,Y)\in\mathcal P(Z)\times\mathcal P(Z): X\cap Y\ne\emptyset\}$ isn't transitive.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, logic, contest-math, relations

Define relation $\sim$ on $\mathcal P(Z)$ as follows: If $X, Y$ are in $\mathcal P(Z)$ (so, subsets of $Z$), we say
$X\sim Y$ when $X\cap Y\ne\emptyset$. Show that $\sim$ is not transitive.

The only thing I know about transitive is if $a,b$ belongs to $R$ and $b,c$ belongs to $R$ then $a,c$ must also belong to $R$.

Comment: Set up a base set $Z$, and play with it's subsets and see which ones are related and which ones aren't. As you need to play with 3 different subsets (your $a, b, c$), you'll need at least 2 elements (to get $2^2 = 4$ subsets), but I'd bet you need 3 to see what is going on (as $\varnothing$ can't be related to any other set, 2 elements just leaves three possibly related subsets). If that doesn't work, play around with related subsets and see how you can build a trio that violates transitivity.

Comment: So you have to come up with subsets $A, B, C \subseteq Z$ such that $A$ and $B$ share an element, $B$ and $C$ share an element, but $A$ and $C$ do not share an element. Can you do this? It might be easiest to think of $Z$ as the set of natural numbers or so.

Comment: @vonbrand You can actually do it already when $Z$ has two elements ;)

Comment: $X\sim Y$ if they have at least one element in common.  So... does $X$ having an element in common with $Y$, as well as $Y$ having an element in common with $Z$ implying anything about $X$ having an element in common with $Z$?  Keep in mind that the element(s) that is common between $X$ and $Y$ does not have to be the same as the element(s) that is common between $Y$ and $Z$.

Comment: This relation isn't reflexive? $\emptyset\subset P(Z)$, but $\emptyset\cap\emptyset=\emptyset$. Just my thoughts.

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya correct, (*though you should have said $\emptyset \in P(Z)$ rather than $\emptyset\subset P(Z)$*).  That is, however, not particularly relevant to the question of transitivity (*but would have been a good question to ask just before or just after this one*)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

For a similar problem, we might be talking about the relation between circles in a plane where one circle is related to another circle if they overlap.

Despite $A$ overlapping $B$ and $B$ overlapping $C$, you can see that $A$ and $C$ do not overlap in the picture below.

[image: overlapping circles]

Relate this to the specific problem you were asked and formalize a counterexample using the same ideas as above.

Comment: I like the geometric picture (and technically, this is a solution not just a hint :p). I just would not choose $Z$ for the third circle, because that was already the entire set in OP's question.

Comment: Fair point., $A,B,C$ then.  I don't know I'll bother remaking the image though.  (*And yes, I agree it is a rather heavy handed hint, especially if $Z$ is an arbitrary set and was allowed to be $\Bbb R^2$.  If $Z$ were specifically the integers as I interpret it to be, then some translation is still necessary*)

Comment: A big part of my goal with this answer was to point out that relations are things we use in everyday language... "this circle overlaps with that"... "these people come from the same family"... "these cars are the same color"... "these people live next door to one another"... Difficulties that some students have with these early problems is more to do with the abstract nature of how we phrase the question rather than the problem itself... If it were asked about overlapping circles to begin with, I would hope that anyone could say "obviously the third circle doesn't have to overlap the first"...

Comment: Since I have nothing better to do in this lockdown situation, I took the liberty to make a new picture and edit your answer. And I agree very much that it is important for students to get an intuition behind all the abstract notations, to "see the picture" so to say (which is why I said I liked the picture).